# Web API.. 401 (Unauthorized) Chrome CORS

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have two sites running. The Classic WebAPI Server and a angular4 client. 
I have CORS Working on the Server. I know that CORS will not work with chrome unless you start Chrome with the security off for localhost. And when I do this all works fine.

But I understood that when I moved off localhost to a site (the site does use a port number. Looks like http://mytest:8080/info) That Chrome would work just fine. But I have the same problem I get 401 (Unauthorized).

It works on IE no problem and if I run chrome with the Security off it works as well.

**Update:**

FIXED like this:

On the server I did the custom Headers like (in web.config)

```
<customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-AspNet-Version,X-Powered-By,Date,Server,Accept,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Cache-Control,Connection,Content-Length,Content-Type,Host,Origin,Pragma,Referer,User-Agent" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
      </customHeaders>
```

in Global.aspx.cs I have

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

      config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
      var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://{serveraddress}:8420", "*", "*");
      config.EnableCors(corsAttr);

      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "DefaultApi",
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
          defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
      );
    }
```

and on the client site I did the call like

```
var options = new RequestOptions({
        headers: new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        }),
        withCredentials: true
    });
    return this.http.get(this.apiAddress + '/api/user', options)
        .map(res => res.json() as user);
}
```

Comment: I read that you can not use * for Access-Control-Allow-Origin with Chrome. so I added the server it is coming form. Still does not work. I read that for IIS6 you cant add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin with the web.config. so I added a filter to add the response headers. still.. same error on Chrome.

Comment: my response looks like: Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-AspNet-Version,X-Powered-By,Date,Server,Accept,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Cache-Control,Connection,Content-Length,Content-Type,Host,Origin,Pragma,Referer,User-Agent
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://xxxyyyzzz:8420
Cache-Control:private